# Eclipse project imported in android studio finishing with non zero exit value 2 exception

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-appcompat

I imported an eclipse project in android studio and it is giving me non zero exit value 2 exception when I try to run it. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your referenced method count with [this tool](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts)

It could be that your app exceeds the maximum number of method references (~65k)

If that's the reason, you could either [follow the documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) or kick out some unused libraries / gradle dependencies (I see you included play services - do you really need the whole library included or only a subset - like maps or analytics - ?)